# PHP exec() and backslash \

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec

I'm trying to run the following command on exec:

```
ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 \
 -ss 1067 -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 32 tmp/cuts/6.ts \
 -ss 1215 -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 32 tmp/cuts/7.ts
```

If i copy this command and run it on a shell everything works great, the video is cutted, perfect.

However running trough php exec, *ffmpeg* returns the following error:

```
[NULL @ 052a0060] Unable to find a suitable output format for '\'
\: Invalid argument
```

Even if i copy paste the command like this:

```
<?php
    $command = 'ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 \
         -ss 1067 -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 32 tmp/cuts/6.ts \
         -ss 1215 -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 32 tmp/cuts/7.ts';

    echo $command.chr(10);

    $return = 0;
    $output = array();
    exec($command, $output, $return);

 ?>
```

Am I missing something? I've tried [escapeshellcmd](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php), [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), even double backslashes to escape the backslash, and nothing.

This happens both in windows and Unix, errors are exactly the same.

Any idea on what's going on with this?

Comment: remove the \'s and make it all one line

Comment: @Dagon, thank you it works perfectly... but the accepted answer goes to Diego, because of the explanation. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash (\) in shell script, in this case, is used only to make it ignore the line break ([Reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_02_01))

So try running the command without the backslash, in a single line:

```
<?php
    $command = 'ffmpeg -y -i video.mp4 -ss 1067 -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 32 tmp/cuts/6.ts -ss 1215 -i video.mp4 -c copy -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts -t 32 tmp/cuts/7.ts';
    (...)
?>
```

Comment: thanks... so that's why it didn't work, I didn't know the \ was to escape the new line